# Python Modules Appear to not be Installing Correctly

Tags: python, crash, pygame

I've tried installing PyGame and it just crashes with the window closing too fast to see the error when I import it. I've tried every package, using the installer or wheel file, but none have worked.

The code I have so far is thus:

```
import pygame

input()
```

The program does not wait for a key press and still just closes at execution.

I am aware there are similar questions already, but none of those solutions have seemed to work.

Comment: please post your code. I have a suspicion about what might be causing the problem, but we need to see the code, please.

Comment: I didn't actually start anything yet, all I did was 'import pygame'

Comment: so all you have in the file is `import pygame` but your program crashes?

Comment: Yes, that's why I assumed it was an issue with installation.

Comment: the issue isn't with installation. if there is nothing in your program, the program will just open and then close really quickly.

Comment: Ok, I jus tried again, but I put an input after so it wouldn't close until I pressed enter. But it still closes.

Comment: im posting an answer in one second. try out the solution there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with installation. If there is nothing in your program, the program will just open and close really quickly.

You can test out your `pygame` module this way.

On Windows, open up the Python command line interpreter. Run:

```
>>> import pygame
>>>
```

You should see just a blank >>> if it loaded correctly.

Same for Linux and OS X, but just type `python` in a terminal to run the interpreter.

If it gives an error, comment the error below and we can go from there.

Comment: It gave a blank just like you said. And strangely after doing that, the script no longer closes when I have an input. Thank you I guess; it worked but I have absolutely no clue why.

Comment: @MatthewH There was likely a mistake somewhere. Either importing it in the interpreter solved some dependency issue or something, or maybe you forgot to save when you tested out the `input()` the first time. Anything is possible. However, if the answer worked, please mark it as correct for other users.